# Python - Outputting Lists

Tags: python

I am creating a program in python that genrates a random passwrod from inputs from the user. My code so far is:

```
from random import *

symbols = ['!','"','£','$','%','^','&','*','(',')','-','_','=','/','*','-','+','{','}','[',']',':',';','@','>','#','~','<',',','.','?']
rand1 = randint(0,32)
rand2 = randint(0,32)

fore = raw_input('Enter your forename')
sur = raw_input('Enter your Surname')
birth = raw_input('Enter you birth year')
password = symbols[rand1], fore[0:2], sur[0:3], birth[2:4], symbols[rand2]
print password
```

When the program outputs the password it looks like this:

```
('+', u'jo', u'smi', u'90', '/')
```

Is there anyway to get rid of the extra characters such as the parenthesis and the commas?

Comment: How did you do? Has any of the answer worked for you?

Comment: @T3H40 The solution you gave worked! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try `print ''.join(password)`.

Have a look at the [documentation](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_join.htm) here. This will join the tuple you created into a string.

*Alternatively* you could join the components directly into a string by using the `+` operator, as it is suggested by @pzp.

Have a look at [this code example](http://codepad.org/8jZEytZU), which shows both possible ways.

Answer (score 1):

```
password = symbols[rand1], fore[0:2], sur[0:3], birth[2:4], symbols[rand2]
```

should be

```
password = symbols[rand1] + fore[0:2] + sur[0:3] + birth[2:4] + symbols[rand2]
```